# Python thinks my tuple is an integer

Tags: python, indexing, integer, int, tuples

I am trying to print out the positions of a given substring inside of a string, but on line 18 I keep getting the error

`Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "prog.py", line 18, in <module>
TypeError: 'int' object has no attribute '__getitem__'`

I have no idea why this is happening, because I am new to python. But anyway, here's my program:

```
sentence = "one two three one four one"
word = "one"

tracked = ()
n = 0
p = 0
for c in sentence:
    p += 1
    if n == 0 and c == word[n]:
        n += 1
        tracked = (p)
    elif n == len(word) and c == word[n]:
        print(tracked[1], tracked[2])
        tracked = ()
        n = 0
    elif c == word[n]:
        n += 1
        tracked = (tracked[1], p)
    else:
        tracked = ()
        n = 0
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

`tracked = (p)` is an integer, not a tuple. The brackets don't necessarily create a tuple, because they're also used for operator precedence in expressions. In this case, it's just evaluating it as an expression so `(p)` gets evaluated to `p`. If you wanted to make it a tuple, you'd need to add a comma `(p,)` which makes it a tuple.

Though in your case you're trying to call `tracked[1], tracked[2]`, neither of which will be valid for a single item tuple. It's unclear what you're trying to do, but tuples are explicitly immutable (meaning they don't change, can't be appended to etc.) and it seems like lists are more likely what you'd need.

Comment: I'm not changing the tuple itself though. I will admit however that tracked[2] was a mistake and should've been 1, and the 1 should've been 0. I'm used to Lua, sorry.

Comment: @warspyking Yeah, it didn't look like you were here but I explained that in case it was useful. And yes, the zero indexing is awkward to get used to when it's new.